# obtaining top 10 posts from reddit using praw

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am trying to obtain the top 10 posts from the subreddit Bitcoin using the praw wrapper but I get an empty list:

import praw

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'XXX',
                    client_secret = 'XXX',
                    username = 'XXX',
                    password = 'XXXX',
                    user_agent = 'XXXXX')

appended_data = []

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('bitcoin')  

top_python = subreddit.top(limit=10)     
for submission in top_python:
    if not submission.stickied:
        appended_data.append(submission.selftext)



appended_data
```

and I obtain the following empty list:

```
Out[105]: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is correct, but the issue is that each of the top ten posts right now are all links.

So for instance, if I change `appended_data.append(submission.selftext)` to `appended_data.append(submission.url)` I get

```
['https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/',
 'http://i.imgur.com/TKiAJWX.gifv',
 'https://i.redd.it/nsokakmrn69z.jpg',
 'https://i.redd.it/djb8i3hoh3zy.jpg',
 'https://i.redd.it/7dvqdd5lbmiz.jpg',
 'https://i.redd.it/4p4r1q4zqvfz.jpg',
 'https://twitter.com/snowden/status/679692055271096321',
 'https://i.redd.it/f4dmhdwzexvy.jpg',
 'https://i.redd.it/giqzirlwg7az.jpg',
 'https://i.redd.it/rkwou70jut8z.jpg']
```

Edit: My bad, didn't see you already answered this

Comment: No worries Daniel, thanks for the answer. By the way, any idea on how to retrieve only those entries which are textual data or obtaining the textual content from the links?

Comment: I believe there's a way to specifically make a call for textual posts only. I would probably loop through the top posts until I found 10 textual posts. And for obtaining textual content, if the link is to another post on reddit, you can get the post id and try to get the text (or link and do the same thing again)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will try that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the top 10 posts are not necessarily textual. Therefore it retrieves an empty list.